# VUE. How on TypeScript support in template?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

as you can see, typescript work in script, but he disabled in template, how can this be fixed?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div><input type="text" v-model="text"></div> <!-- nothing -->
    <button @click="text = 'why'">click</button> <!-- nothing -->
    <div>{{text}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const text = ref(0)
text.value = '' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
</script>
```

Comment: You should use the [volar extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar)

Comment: Will `const text = ref('')` will solve the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

I think is indifferent for `<template>` tag, it's like an "HTML" with dynamic data being received so I think Vue will only care for the `<script>` tag

Comment: no, I just reload window in vsc and it worked for the button, but still not for the v-model